# Differences between: INT 10H , INT 16H, INT 21H

Tags: assembly, binary, emulation, x86-16

Could anyone please explain to me the differences between: INT 10H , INT 16H, INT 21H in assembly language? When should we use any of them and for what?

For example: in this simple code for printing "Hello, World!" 
Why did we use int 10h in the fourth line?
Why did we use int 16h in the line before the last?

```
name "hi-world"
org 100h     
mov ax, 3     
int 10h      
mov ax, 1003h
mov bx, 0
int 10h
mov ax, 0b800h
mov ds, ax
mov [02h], 'H'

mov [04h], 'e'

mov [06h], 'l'

mov [08h], 'l'

mov [0ah], 'o'

mov [0ch], ','

mov [0eh], 'W'

mov [10h], 'o'

mov [12h], 'r'

mov [14h], 'l'

mov [16h], 'd'

mov [18h], '!'


mov cx, 12  ; number of characters.
mov di, 03h ; start from byte after 'h'

c:  mov [di], 11101100b 
add di, 2 ; skip over next ascii code in vga memory.
loop c

; wait for any key press:
mov ah, 0
int 16h

ret
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all `INT` means interrupt and has nothing to do with `int` data type.

Each `INT` represents a functions family, where usually the value stored in the `AH` register represents the function number.

For example :

1. INT 0x10 is used for screen manipulation

- AH=0x00 -> set video mode
- AX=0x1003 -> Set Blinking mode
- AH=0x13 -> write string
- AH=0x03 -> get cursor position

1. INT 0x13 is for storage (HDD and FDD)

- AH=0x42 -> DISK READ
- AH=0x43 -> DISK WRITE

1. INT 0x16 is for Keyboard control and read:

- AH=0x00 -> GetKey
- AH=0x03 -> Set typematic rate and delay

You can find all these functions here: [Interrupt Jump Table](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm)

But these are just BIOS INT, which can be rewritten by OS during startup. For example, Windows uses `INT 0x2E` for communication between user space and kernel space; Linux-based use `INT 0x80`. See also [Linux System Call Table](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html)

In your code:

- INT 0x10 with AH = 0x00 and AL = 3 (`mov ax, 3`) means: set video mode to TextMode 80x25 chars and 16 colors.
- INT 0x10 with AX = 0x1003 means: TOGGLE INTENSITY/BLINKING BIT to background intensity enabled

Comment: Last time I checked Windows used `int 0x2e` for syscalls.  The entry point `int 0x21` is for DOS calls.

Answer (score 6):

With regard to this piece of your question:

> When should we use any of them and for what?

Probably never.

These BIOS interrupts were primarily used by MS-DOS applications, and are essentially obsolete today. They are not available at runtime to applications running on any modern operating system, so you will likely never use them. (Exceptions might include if you are developing certain pieces of software which run very early in the boot process, such as a bootloader, firmware for a hardware device, or if you are developing the BIOS itself.)

Answer (score 1):

*INT* here stands for INTERRUPT and it has Function Mode such as 00,01,02 and so on, `INT 10h` is used for graphic and video mode initialization, and `INT 16h` is used to set the keyboard stroke.